# File System Watcher MacOX

Tags: macos, filesystemwatcher

I have been asked to create a file system watcher for a file created or changed event in Mac OSX, but I must say I am not a Mac developer (yet), but thought that this would be simple (famous last words)

I have had a look at the documentation but cannot see how or where the event is wired up to look for the change.

Ive also looked here, [Emcrisostomo/fswatch git hub repo](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch#building-from-source) but this may be complete over kill for what I need.

[Link to apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4)

I am only looking for the change to one file, held in a single location, any and all help would be very much appreciated

Comment: There's a tool already, called `fswatch`. You can install it with `homebrew` using `brew install fswatch`.

Comment: HI Mark, When the file is changed or created i need to perform some actions such as uploading to FTP servers which is why i need to create a custom one, but first I need to understand how this works

Comment: Just run `fswatch . | while read x; do ... done`

Comment: am i able to get this to run as a service?

Comment: Yes, it is called `launchd` on Macs. You control it with `launchctl`... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html

Comment: You're welcome - questions are free. so just ask away! :-) Good luck.